# PHP - Sorting an Associative array by another array's values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays, one is a multidimensional array which holds information, the other is a simple array which holds values for the order I want the first array in.

For example, I want my first array to be ordered by ID, by the values in the second array.

$users array:

```
array(3) {
    [0] => array(3) {
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'John Smith',
            'email' => 'john@example.com',
        },
    [2] => array(3) {
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Jane Smith',
            'email' => 'jane@example.com',
        },
    [0] => array(3) {
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'Jack Smith',
            'email' => 'Jack@example.com',
        },
}
```

$order array:

```
array(3) {
    [0] => '2',
    [1] => '3',
    [2] => '1',
}
```

What I would like the outcome of the sorted array to be:

```
array(3) {
    [0] => array(3) {
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Jane Smith',
            'email' => 'jane@example.com',
        },
    [2] => array(3) {
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'Jack Smith',
            'email' => 'jack@example.com',
        },
    [0] => array(3) {
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'John Smith',
            'email' => 'John@example.com',
        },
}
```

So as you can see, I would like the array keys to be reindexed, so they are always sequential starting from 0, but for the values of each element in the $users array to be re ordered.

Comment: take a look at [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this like this:

```
// Index users by ID
$users = array_combine(
    array_column($users, 'id'),
    $users
);

// Order the users
$users = array_map(function ($id) use ($users) {
    return $users[$id];
}, $order);
```

Here I used [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function, that creates array by mapping given keys to values. For the keys I used all the id's in a sequential order (grabbed them with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)).

Having an array in such form, I can loop over `$order` array and grab the values from `$users` array by index, that actually have the value of `id` now.

Instead of looping with `foreach` I used [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function. If you have a collection (i.e. array) it is better to use [higher order functions](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Functional-Programming.html) to process them. If you are a beginner it can be overwhelming, but you have to learn this, as this is the way things done nowadays.

[Here is working example.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/57c0b667fd1462eac75aa39406e3df4ea1f2f044)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to achieve this :

```
        // the key order of each id
        $orderIdKeys  = array_flip($order);

        usort($users, function ($u1, $u2)  use ($orderIdKeys) {

            // compare the keys of the ids in the $order array
            return $orderIdKeys[$u1['id']] >= $orderIdKeys[$u2['id']] ?  1 : -1;
        });
```

Then  `$users` should be ordered.

The [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) here is comparing users based on the position ( which is `$orderIdKeys[$u1['id']]` )  of each user id in $order array, If the **position** of `$u1['id']` is greater than the **position** of `$u2['id']` the callback returns 1 which means `$u2` should be placed before `$u1` in the final ordered array

Answer (score -1):

I think that this should do the job:

```
$array = array(
    array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Jane Smith',
            'email' => 'jane@example.com',
    ),
    array(
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'Jack Smith',
            'email' => 'Jack@example.com',
    ),
    array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'John Smith',
            'email' => 'john@example.com',
    ),
);

function cmp_by_optionNumber($a, $b) {
  return $a["id"] - $b["id"];
}
usort($array, "cmp_by_optionNumber");

var_dump($array);
```

It will sort your main array by the values of the "id" keys in the subarrays.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question